# How can I encrypt / decrypt AES-256 CBC with OpenSSL?

Tags: encryption, aes, decryption

I just installed Linux (Ubuntu) for the first time and downloaded package OpenSSL as well. Opened command line too and tried some commands but none of them worked.

So what I have is initial vector: `5a04ec902686fb05a6b7a338b6e07760`, also have ciphertext: `14c4e6965fc2ed2cd358754494aceffa` and the corresponding plaintext: `We're blown. Run`

Now I imagine there must be a command where you enter the initial vector and the plaintext and as a result you should get the ciphertext...?
Another possibility: Enter initial vector and ciphertext, get the plaintext.

But how can I do this in the command line? I've already tried the command:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -e -nosalt -a -in  input.txt -out  output.txt -k key -iv ivkey
```

about `input.txt`: I have created this file on my Desktop and wrote the plaintext in it. About `output.txt`, I created it as well and put it on Desktop, it's empty. After using this command, nothing happens!

Is there any other command that could help me? I have also tried to find some helpful tool on the internet but nothing seemed to work! : /

Comment: The `-k` should be `-K` if you want to specify the raw hex key.

Comment: @forest Thank you! But still nothing happens ^^

Comment: You also don't want `-a` if you want a hex output. Pipe it to `xxd` instead. Since the plaintext and ciphertext are both exactly 16 bytes you'll also want `-nopad`.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald Great it seems like I got one step further. Now I'm asked to "enter aes-256-cbc encryption password". I just entered "1" 32 times but again, nothing has happened after.

Comment: Then it seems it doesn't realize that you are specifying the raw keys. Remember to use `-K` with the hex key and `-iv` with the hex IV. That will allow it to take that directly rather than prompting you for a password. When it's asking you for a password, it is looking for ASCII which it will hash with SHA-256 (on newer builds) or MD5 (on older builds) before using directly as the key.

Comment: @forest as hex key -K i have just used the ciphertext. Maybe that was the mistake? But what else can I use if that caused the problem?

Comment: You have to use the key used to encrypt it. If you don't know the key you can't decrypt it...that's how cryptography works.

Comment: @roblind The ciphertext is in the file for `-in` (if you're doing decryption). `-K` is for the key, not the ciphertext.

Comment: @forest Ok the final command I used: openssl aes-256-cbc -d xxd -nosalt -nopad -in theciphertext -out output.txt -iv theinitialvector but I'm still asked for the password

Comment: You're still missing the `-K`. And what's the xxd in there for? You'd want to use xxd to view the file after decryption.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Prepare input text:

```
echo "We're blown. Run" >input.txt
```

Encrypt:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -e \
        -in input.txt -out input.txt.enc \
        -K '2222233333232323' -iv '5a04ec902686fb05a6b7a338b6e07760'
```

Decrypt to stdout original text:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -d \
        -in input.txt.enc \
        -K '2222233333232323' -iv '5a04ec902686fb05a6b7a338b6e07760'
```

**Note 1**: for `-K` and `-iv` you must pass [*a string comprised only of hex digits*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-enc.html#:%7E:text=be%20represented%20as-,a%20string%20comprised%20only%20of%20hex%20digits,-.%20If%20only%20the). You can get this string from a binary file like this:

```
hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"' FILE_WITH_KEY
```

**Note 2**: Here I used **AES-256** algo that get key of 256-bit length. But in `-K` there is only *8 bytes/16 hex/64 bits*. In this case `openssl` pads private key with zeros, so in example above used the following key: `'2222233333232323000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'`. This is a significant weakening, **please use more strong keys in real life**.
The same story refer to `-iv`, but it's length depends on chosen algorithm's mode and block length, [see related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90848/encrypting-using-aes-256-can-i-use-256-bits-iv).